# .net error capturing open source project?

Tags: .net

I am already using Log4net to log errors to a file, however because of the way it works with try/catch blocks I am loosing the original context of the error.

Is there a good opensource error logging platform for .net that you can add to your solutions to make it much easier to detect where errors are occuring in your code?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you re-throwing like this?:

```
throw ex;
```

or like this?:

```
throw;
```

(the former loses the stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflows uses [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), and I have also used this library with great success.